# Joining same table but different columns, is there a difference between these 2 approaches?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

If you want to build a query that joins the same table but on different columns is there a a difference between these two approaches?

The first approach using two JOIN statements:

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     docs
JOIN authors on 
     docs.author_id = authors.id 
JOIN authors a2 ON 
     docs.id = a2.id
```

Versus the second approach, using one JOIN statement but combining it with the AND operator:

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     docs
JOIN authors on 
     docs.id = authors.id
     AND docs.author_id = authors.id
```

Looking at the output here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7c9e0/11 it gives the same results if I'm not mistaken (the number of columns in the result differs of course but it gives back the same row). Why though? Are these queries exactly the same? And does this also apply when using the other join types like left join, right join etc?

Comment: I would expect three tables, one for the authors, one for the documents and the connection between authors and documents. Your current model can only have one author for each document.

Comment: No, the two queries are not the same and they produce identical result because of your data only. To be honest your join logic matching the ids ftom both tables does not seem to be valid, but only you know your data!

Comment: Good points about the data model. Its just artificial data, made for this question. I've probably should have used a less confusing example. However, is the difference that the first approach "creates" more intermediate tables?

Comment: Please ask 1 question. [mre] Please put all & only what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. [ask] [Help] Show what you are able to do towards answering. Research before considering asking & reflect research in a question. [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) PS Please don't say "same result" when you don't mean the same result. This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please tell us why you expect what you expect with justification per to authoritative documentation. Otherwise you are just expecting us to rewrite it & to write a bespoke tutorial where we walk through the code (& when you weren't willing to) & you don't give any details of what you misunderstand or do or don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I believe those queries are actually very different.

In the first case you actually join three tables (the "authors" twice), so the resulting table is supposed to have double set of columns from the "author" table.

Here is an example of how it works with more records
[two joins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Vgc.png)

[join by two conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt8T2.png)

Answer (score -1):

As you say, the second query will yield additional columns but they will have an identical result in terms of rows.

What could vary is the performance. Instinctively I’d expect the single join on both columns to be faster, especially if you have an index on the two id columns on both tables.

What you might find interesting though is if you put the keyword EXPLAIN before each select you can see a description of the query plan for each query which will show you how MySQL is going about retrieving the data. It’s even possible that the engine is clever enough to optimise the first query to be more like the second.